# find div in html with javascript and regex

Tags: javascript, html

I try to select html element with javascript without! jQuery...

for example my html is:

```
<div id="my1231">
</div>
```

and i want to select any first div with id started with my, and i try so:

```
var regex = /my(.*)/; 
var templateCode = document.match(regex)
alert(templateCode);
```

but nothing happend, what i do wrong? 
how to select div with regex, where first part of id is static, and second random?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use regex to match against ids, you must first get a node list and then loop through it and check each id individually. You can then append each matching element to a new array:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var regex = /my(.*)/, matches = [];

for(i=0; i< divs.length; i++){
    if(regex.test(divs[i].id)){
        matches.push(divs[i]);  
    }
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6bnyd/1/)

Comment: That's because `matches` contains an array of nodes. `innerHTML` is a property of a single node.

Comment: I think the test would be better as `regex.test(divs[i].id)`.

Comment: but did it select something? maybe no... becouse if i work as with array - nothing is selected  http://jsfiddle.net/779vy/3/

Comment: @RobG You're right, thanks. Valdis, sorry, I don't understand?

Comment: see my last fiddle? it must select something, but nothing is selected  i must select div with id  /serv_paragraph(.*)/  and all it's child

Comment: In your fiddle, `serv_paragraph` comes at the beginning of a class, not an id.

Comment: and what? http://jsfiddle.net/779vy/7/  with class same - npthing. what i need to change

Comment: @ValdisAzamaris The property is [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className) not `class`

Comment: even if so, it didn't find it, could you test your code on my example? and find solution?

Answer (score 6):

How about `document.querySelectorAll`?

```
document.querySelectorAll("[id^='my']")
```

Just be aware of the >= IE8 support

http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelectorAll

Comment: hm, cross browser must be)

Comment: Do you need to select only the first div with ID that starts with my or all the divs that start with it?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can always mix both answers and use feature detection to determine which method to use:

```
var divs;
var matches = [];
var re = /^my\w+/;

if (document.querySelectorAll) {
  matches = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='my']");

} else if (document.getElementsByTagName) {
  divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

  for(i=0, iLen=divs.length; i<iLen; i++){

    if (re.test(divs[i].id)) {
      matches.push(divs[i]);  
    }
  }
}
```

HTH.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/779vy/6/   it must select div with id /serv_paragraph(.*)/ and all it's child    and it didn't do it...

Comment: It does, but there are no divs in that fiddle with an ID starting with "serv_paragraph". There is one with a **class** that starts with that string though.